# Bootstrap-3.2.0 popover doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

in the BundleConfig.cs, I added bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css files and in layout page I rendered that files using the below codes :

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

and than in my Index page, I want to use popover tool. my Index.cshtml file:

```
<div class="container" style="padding: 100px 50px 10px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Popover title"
        data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"
        data-content="Some content in Popover on left">Popover on left
    </button>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();
    });
</script>
```

By the way I am using bootstrap-3.2.0 so bootstrap.js file includes all plugins, doesn't it? I couldn't find where I do a mistake. Thanks in advance.

Edit-1 :

I've realized something. In my layout page I had been added this line:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but I have already bootstrap.js file and when I delete above line, all components doesn't work such as dropdown etc. If I've got bootstrap.js file, all components must work, mustn't they?

Edit-2 : my BundleConfig class :

```
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
```

Comment: any console errors???

Comment: It is possible, that javascript and css are not found in folder. Also, it is important to have corrcet order of scripts.

Comment: no, there is no error. Just doesnt working when I click the button.

Comment: By the way, I edited my question.

Comment: To test your bundles use: BundlesTable.EnableOptimialisations = true; You will get a bunch of error consoles if they don't work.

Comment: Does your jQuery bundle contain the Bootstrap files, or have you put them into a new bundle. Looks like you are only rendering the jQuery bundle. If the Bootstrap files are in the jQuery bundle then thats fine. Have you checked the source of the actual page that is rendered to see if it includes the links for the Bootstrap files?

Comment: I edited my problem again. According to my BundleConfig class, my bootstrap files are in the jquery bundle.

Comment: now my popover is working but I don't know why it didn't work or why it worked now :( nevertheless thanks your replies.